# GridView Dynamic ItemTemplate EditIndex After Filtering

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, filter, indexing

I have a dynamically generated gridview with custom datasource.

The gridview allows "editing, inserting, and deleting"

Everything (all features) are working fine..

I then added a filtering feature to the gridview..

Let's say previously my datasource is based on this select statement:

```
SELECT * FROM <Table>
```

Now, after filter:

```
SELECT * FROM <Table> WHERE <Filter Condition>
```

After filtering.. I am not able to do the editing (updating) gridview properly.. As during the editing mode..

```
   public void gvGridView_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {   
        gvGridView.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        ((TemplateField)gvGridView.Columns[1]).EditItemTemplate = null;
        //disable editing on primary key

        if (txtSearch.Text != string.Empty || CountRow() > 0)
        {
            FilterQuery(); //refilter the gridview
        }
        else
        {                
            gvGridView.DataBind();
            //if gridview is not meant to be filtered, just leave it as it is
        }
        Session["SelecetdRowIndex"] = e.NewEditIndex;
    }
```

Due to this line:

> gvGridView.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;

The editindex will not be initialized correctly. For example:

1. Before filter it was index no 8
2. After filter it is index no 1

If i edit this gridview after filter what it will do is it will take 1 as the edit index (supposedly 8)... hence instead of updating data on index 8.. it will override data with index number 1...

I hope my question is clear enough.. looking forward to hear some answers :)..

**Edit:**

This what happens during gridview updating:

```
GridViewRow row = gvGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex];
//decide which row being edited..

for (int i = 0; i < Table.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            string field_value = ((TextBox)row.FindControl(Table.Columns[i].ColumnName)).Text;
            ParameterArray.Add(field_value);
            //storing all value in that row into an array (including PK)
        }
```

The code above works fine (store all value into array) except for the primary key.. (always store e.rowindex value)..

Comment: Obviously e.NewEditIndex  will return from starting only.You have to edit or delete basing on primary key not on index.

Comment: pls elaborate, as i provide the updates..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In row updating event in  cs page:

```
protected void Grid_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
   TextBox txtId = (TextBox)Grid.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtId_insql");
   //Get the Id for which row is clicked
}
```

In aspx page:

```
<Gridview>
<column>
 <asp:BoundColumn DataField="txtId_insql" HeaderText="PrimaryID" Visible="False"></asp:BoundColumn> 
</columns>
</GridView>
```

so you will get the ID.You can update using the Id now.Not with the Index.

Answer (score -1):

Don't update data based on grid Index, just find the key(like primary key) based on that Index and then update you data based on that key and bind your grid again.